# Multiple documentation comments for one function JS

Tags: javascript, function, visual-studio-code, code-documentation

So I want to create a function as follows:

- Using various amount of arguments

  ```
  /**
   * Stuff with one argument.
   * @method foo
   * @param {type} a One argument.
   */
  /**
   * Stuff with  more arguments.
   * @method foo
   * @param {type} a1 Argument one.
   * @param {type} a2 Argument two enz.
   */
  function foo() {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      // Awesome code thats doing stuff with more arguments
    } else {
      // Awesome code thats doing stuff with one argument
    }
  }
  ```
- Using different types of arguments

  ```
  /**
   * Stuff with string argument.
   * @method doo
   * @param {string} s String argument.
   */
  /**
   * Stuff with number argument.
   * @method doo
   * @param {number} n Number argument.
   */
  function doo() {
    if (typeof arguments[0] == "string") {
      // Awesome code thats doing stuff with string
    } else if (typeof arguments[0] == "number") {
      // Awesome code thats doing stuff with number
    }
  }
  ```

Now in my lovely VSCode will show this:
[image]

How can I accomplish that I can step through the different documentation comments?

Comment: Remove the `*/ /*` inbetween?

Comment: I'd suggest using optional parameter syntax:  `@param {type2} [a2] - Argument two enz.` [More here](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-param.html#optional-parameters-and-default-values)

Comment: Made an edit @Andrey. I use sometimes one argument and check on different types

Answer (score 0):

```
@param {(View[] | string)} n - insert childrens or plain text
```